# BroadcastReceiver without activity

Tags: android

I've an Activity that starts after boot completed, Autostart class calls an Activity (notify). I need to start Notify.class without activity. How I will change Notify code? thanks!

```
AutoStart

public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Notify.class);  
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);  
}

Notify

public class Notify extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 05);
cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
if(now.after(cal1))
    cal1.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
if(now.after(cal2))
    cal2.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent morningAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
PendingIntent eveningAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, morningAlarm);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, eveningAlarm);
```

Comment: Just create the alarms in onReceive function of AutoStart class?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an Activity to issue a notification, but you do need an Android component. What is starting on boot? Whichever class that is can issue a notification.

Comment: Autostart class call an Activity and notification are ok. When I start emulator, starts an empty activity and later a notification. Now, I need only notification without activity